# Console not showing up on Xcode Playground 7.1.1

Tags: console, xcode7, swift-playground

This is what Standard Editor looks like: [image]

This is what Assistant Editor looks like:[image]
This is a problem because whether I click on the eye icon or the + next to (6 times), it shows me a graph only:[image] I was wondering if there would be a way to show more useful output?

Edit: When I show the debug area, it doesn't show any output there: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the console by the menu

> View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area

There's also a little upper arrow icon in the bottom left of the Playground, and the `SHIFT+CMD+Y` shortcut.

In the console you will be able to see not only the error messages but also anything you `print`.

---

To be able to see the output in the preview panel you have to place the statement you want to see on a separate line, and break down the logic on separate lines up to some point.

In your case, for example:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let triple = arr.map({
    (i:Int) -> Int in
    return i*3
})
```

Here with `let triple ...` not being *on the same line as the closure* anymore, the Playground is able to preview it.

[image]

And by clicking on the `+` on the right side, you can now unfold the special panel where all values are visible:

[image]

Comment: Edit in original post: The debug area doesn't show output

Comment: If there's no error message and if you don't `print`, there's nothing here of course. What are you looking for exactly? What do you expect to show up which doesn't? I may be able to help.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to display the output rather than manually looping through the array to print? In the tutorial I watched, the second line was able to display the value returned in each iteration of the loop.